# How to check the status of Mongo DB that crashes all the time

Tags: mongodb, performance, database, nosql

I have a lot of write and read activity in my Mongo DB. After running it for a while the DB crashes and I need to clear all records and restart it. I think it is because it is using too much memory. (10000 records every minute)

I need to find the root cause.

Here are results from  `db.serverStatus().mem` and `db.stats()`:

`db.serverStatus().mem`

[image]

`db.stats()`

[image]

How can I tell from this whether my mongo is healthy?

Please, could you provide me some guidance?

Comment: Based on these values, filesize is not very high (if values are in bytes then its 2GB which is very low) and even 10000 read/write rate is also very low. Check resource utilization of mongo node.

Comment: This belongs on dba, but you really should take a look at your mongo log instead of speculating on what the cause might be based on stats

Comment: Database operation is a topic for administrators, not for software developers. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com. I assume the dba experts would be interested in what "the DB crashes" exactly means. Is there any error message? Regarding memory usage: MongoDB always grabs all the memory it can get for caching documents. This is normal behavior.

Comment: 1) Collect the logs from all the mongod and read them. The problem might be in here. A mongod doesn't just stop like that without saying something in the logs.
2) Monitor your servers : CPU, IOs, RAM...